# Can't upload to Arduino UNO (kuman UNO)

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I am trying to upload my code to my new Arduino (Just got one today, so im very new).

I can compile my code with no problems, but uploading it gives me:

```
[Arduino: 1.6.11 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Sketch uses 1,186 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude_bin: Read-only file system
/private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude: line 6: /private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude_bin: Permission denied
/private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude: line 6: exec: /private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude_bin: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
/private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude: line 6: exec: /private/var/folders/md/s6pczlkd6gq8ylyh13z_3z8r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/0D981E7A-E386-4AFD-9AEC-35E9ED8DA180/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude_bin: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

It doesn't matter what i upload (tried to upload some of the examples).

As said i am very new, so if you need any more information to help me just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your question appropriately. In this case the big block you copy-pasted here should be contained within a `code` block (the button with two curly brackets `{}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag Arduino.app out of your ~/Downloads folder to /Applications or anywhere else that isn't where you downloads it to. The app is being subjected to Gatekeeper Path Randomization which means it is running on a read-only file system. The app is trying to chmod something inside the app bundle and thats not possible on a read-only file system.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that this was a thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your port to which your arduino is connected. The port name can be checked from Arduino IDE. Click Tools -> Port -> There you can find the port name.
Open Terminal and type the following command.

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/port_name
```

After this try to Recompile/Upload the code again.

Comment: i ran `sudo chmod 777 /dev/cu.usbmodem1411`. Still same problem.

Comment: Are you sure? You are using correct port name?Try dmesg | grep tty
to list all Serial Device Converter

Comment: Try to run your Arduino IDE with super user privileges,  because the  compilation log shows most of the errors are related to inadequate rights of writing/executing on files.

Comment: I ran `sudo /Users/madsankernielsen/Downloads/Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino` and now it won't even compile it. Am i doing it right?